# Vagrant - logout and re-login during provisioning without losing the provision state

Tags: vagrant

I am installing a script while provisioning that requires a logout and re-login after it finishes.

The problem is that I want to provision more scripts right after.

Is it possible to log out and login in vagrant without losing the provisioning?

this is the script: http://rextester.com/AKZDK39013

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a plugin such as [vagrant reload](https://github.com/aidanns/vagrant-reload/blob/master/README.md).

An example snippet of a Vagrantfile to highlight its possible use:

```
  # execute code before reload
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
     echo $(date) > ~/rebootexample
  SHELL

  # trigger reload
  config.vm.provision :reload

  # execute code after reload
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
     echo $(date) >> ~/rebootexample
  SHELL
```